# How to make each row have its own header with section-like behavior?

Tags: ios, header, row, each

I have a little problem in xcode:

I want to create a tableview with separate headers for each row in my array - Much like it is done in the Instagram-app, but I can't figure out how to get the behaviour from sections (pushing one after the other off the screen, but staying anchored to the bottom of the navbar, when you are "between headers").

I can make a number of sections OR I can make a number of rows using 1 section, but I can't figure out how to make X number of sections with 1 row in each and still keep track of the rows (indexPath messes up, obvi).

I would like to show you a lot of code, but I haven't really gotten that close to solving my problem...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return [array count];
}
```

OR

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return [array count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so here's the answer if anyone out there is interested in making a tableview with headers (much like the Instagram tableview):

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return [yourArray count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 1;

}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [TableName dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


cell.bodyText.text = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"bodytext"];

return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [[yourArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"headertext"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Treat each row as its own section.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return array.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return 1;
}
```

Give each section a title.

Comment: Yeah, that's the part I can't really figure out, though.

Comment: Which part can't you figure out? Be specific.

Comment: Okay,

In order to fill my rows with values from the array I use:

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
// code her
}

But when I use the above mentioned method, this is no longer possible, since there's only 1 row in each section...

Comment: You use the `indexPath.section` to access each element of the array.